# How to target just the child of a JSON object in Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

I seem to have managed to write a script that affects everything in the `$scope`, is there a way to target jus the child of the JSON object/just feed in feeds with the 'like'?

Here is a Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/IGxw8P7YT85jVRMnOVgU

Thanks,

JP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `feed` object to the click handler so that it knows which feed to modify:

```
<button ng-show="!feed.isLiked" ng-click="likeClicked(feed)">Like</button>
```

The click handler updates the "like" state of the feed:

```
$scope.likeClicked = function (feed) {
    feed.isLiked = !feed.isLiked;
};
```

Here is an updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/4WX14PfAnkcFOaRWJOGz?p=preview